# Multiple Relationship Laravel - Object in Object

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I want use Laravel Eloquent to do relationship, but  I have a problem accessing a specific filtered object in the relationship.

My objects:

```
courses:  
  id - integer
  name - string

contents:
  id - integer
  name - string

course_contents:
  id - integer
  course_id - integer
  content_id - integer
```

I want get the contents by the course. Until now I can only filter the course_contents to filter contents

My controller:

```
Course::hasContents()->find($id);
```

Course Model

```
public function contents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CourseContent');
    }

    public function scopeHasContents($query)
    {
        $query->with(['contents' => function($contentQuery) {
            $contentQuery->has('content')->with('content');
        }]);
    }
```

CourseContents Model:

```
public function content()
    {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Content', 'id');
    }
```

My json return ( Course Find ) :

```
{  
    "id":1,
    "name":"Course Example 1",
    "contents":[  
        {  
            "id":1,
            "course_id":1,
            "content_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05",
            "updated_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05",
            "content":{  
                "id":1,
                "name":"Content Example 1",
                "deleted_at":null,
                "created_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05",
                "updated_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05"
            }
        },
        {  
            "id":2,
            "course_id":1,
            "content_id":2,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05",
            "updated_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05",
            "content":{  
                "id":2,
                "name":"Content Example 2",
                "deleted_at":null,
                "created_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05",
                "updated_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05"
            }
        },{ ... }
    ],
}
```

What I need:

```
{  
    "id":1,
    "name":"Course Example 1",
    "contents":[  
        {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Content Example 1",
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05",
            "updated_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05"

        },
        {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"Content Example 2",
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05",
            "updated_at":"2019-07-16 17:31:05"

        },{ ... }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to adjust the relationships a bit. You've many to many relationships so the models should look like:

`Course.php`

```php
public function contents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Content::class, 'course_contents');
}
```

`Content.php`

```php
protected $hidden = ['pivot'];

public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_contents');
}
```

You can retrieve `contents` data as given below:
for instance: you want to get all contents for a course `1`

```php
Content::whereHas('courses', function($query) {
    $query->where('courses.id', 1);
})->get();

// You need to pass course id dynamically but for demonstration, I hard coded it.
```

This will give you the following result:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Content 1"
  ]
]
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question correctly, I updated the responses to clarify a little more.

Comment: Got it, so you can hide the `pivot` table information in the `Content` model. I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the `belongsToMany` relationship:

In your `Course` model:

```php
public function contents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Contents::class, 'course_contents');
}
```

Then, use `$course->contents;`

This function returns all content models of the course.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The many-to-many relationship is defined by returning a belongsToMany relationship in the relationship method `contents` in the `Course` model. As stated in the [Laravel many-to-many documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

To retrieve only the `Content` items in the many to many relationship and not the pivot columns, you should change the relationship instance from `App\CourseContent` to `App\Content`.

Answer (score 0):

in content model

```
public function course()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Course');
    }
```

in course model

```
public function content()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Content');
    }
```

you can do

```
Course::with('content')->find($id)
```

or

```
Content::whereHas('course',function($q)use($id){
$q->where('id',$id)
})->get();
```